# Changing CSS permanently with cookies

Tags: jquery, css, cookies

I'm making a small site with some jQuery-experiments (kinda' gamish). In each game there is a goal, and when the goal is found, and clicked, I want to make a permanent change to the heart symbols in the footer. I'm trying to use the cookie-plugin for this.

A link to one of the subpages: http://www.carlpapworth.com/htmlove/arrows.html

here's the footer CSS:

```
footer{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
padding: 10px; 
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background: /*url(../images/bgFooter.png)*/ #dddddd;
z-index: 2000;
}

.heartCollection{
width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: justify;
}

.heartCollection p{
font-size: 13px;
float: none;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 0 -20px 0;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
}

.heartCollection ul li{
width: auto;
display: inline;
list-style: none;
float: left;
margin: 10px 0 -10px 0;
padding: 0 0 0 98px;
font-size: 70px;
}

.heartCollection ul li a{
font-family: menlo;
color: #cccccc;
}

.found{
color: #ff63ff;
}

.credits{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
margin: 80px auto;
bottom: 0px;
left: -40px;
position: relative;
text-align: right;
}
```

Here's the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //help
    $('#helpInfo').hide();
    $('#help h2').click(function(){
        $('#helpInfo').show(300);
    });
    $('#helpInfo').click(function() {
        $(this).hide(300);
    });
    //reward  
    $('#reward').hide();
    $('#goal a').click(function(){
        $('#reward').fadeIn(1000);
    });
    //Collection
    $.cookie('class','found',{
    });
    var foundHeart = $.cookie('found');
    $('.exit').click(function(){
        $('#collection1').addClass(foundHeart);
    });

});
```

Well nothing happens, so what am I doing wrong? 
Edit: And more importantly, what should I do to fix it?

Comment: You just created another game: find the bug!

Comment: RomanTheGreat is right, you are trying to get a cookie with the name `found` while the name is actually `class`. Anyway, I love the idea! Bookmarked ;)

Comment: Cool,well I still haven't gotten it to work, but if it would be neat :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong:

First,

```
var foundHeart = $.cookie('found');
```

You're trying to retrieve the cookie by name with the above function.  Instead you're passing in the value.

The cookie params are set as follows:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value', { options });
```

So the name of your cookie is 'class' and the value is 'found'.

In other words

```
var foundHeart = $.cookie('found');
```

should be

```
var foundHeart = $.cookie('class');
```

Second, even if you correct that your code won't function as you intended.  Why?  Because you're setting the cookie on load.

This line sets the cookie:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value');
```

But you're running it within the document ready function.

You should move that line into this function:

```
$('#goal a').click(function(){
    $('#reward').fadeIn(1000);
    // moved set cookie function here
    $.cookie('class', 'found');
});
```

So that it only sets when you get to the goal.

Comment: You mean like the line above ´var = foundHeart´?

EDIT: So I should really cut out the line above the var, and paste it after the =?

Comment: I've added additional explanation.  You're main problem after fixing the cookie call is that you're setting it on load.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var foundHeart = $.cookie('class');
```

you should get the cookie by name not by value : )

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin:
https://github.com/tantau-horia/jquery-SuperCookie

Create the heart default cookie if it doesn't exist:

```
//name of the cookie: hearts
//name of the hearts: h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
//values: 1 if active, 0 if inactive
if ( !$.super_cookie().check("hearts") ) {
   $.super_cookie().create("hearts",{h1:"0",h2:"0",h3:"0",h4:"0",h5:"0",h6:"0"});
};
```

When a goal is found (example for goal 1)

```
$("#collection1").addClass('foundHeart');
$.super_cookie().replace_value("hearts","h1","1")
```

On page reload remember if heart is selected

```
if ( $.super_cookie().read_value("hearts","h1") == "1" ) {
   $("#collection1").addClass('foundHeart');
};
```

Comment: Cool I'll definitely try this :)